# Xamarin : HttpClient fails with some URLs (TaskCanceledException)

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient, portable-class-library

In my Xamarin.Forms project, System.Net.Http.HttpClient fails with some URLs. I've got an obscure message :

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

I don't know how to retrieve the exact message...

Examples :

HttpClient works with :

http://stackoverflow.com

https://www.nytimes.com/

HttpClient fails with (only in Xamarin, works elsewhere : WPF, ConsoleApp... etc) :

http://www.leparisien.fr

https://www.google.fr/

EDIT 1: From Xamarin.Android I have the same behaviour, whether I use HttpClient , WebClient or Restsharp.

Comment: What do you mean "System.Net.Http.HttpClient fails" ? Can you show your sample code of the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour happens only with Visual Studio Emulator for Android, When I deploy on a google Emulator or a real device I don't have that problem. Weird cause when I use compiled code from Android Studio with these URLs it works.

I also had other problems with other URLs, I had to use ModernHttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use [Flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/). I am using it in every project, with no problem!
Also, provide more informations about your error!

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code to post a data using Flurl to a web api by passing cookies like this when using http client :  CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    cookies.SetCookies(uri, strArray[0]);
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

Comment: Which api are you using, you can find sample code [here](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/)

Comment: I've got the same behaviour with Flurl. And btw it's syntax is awful.